# What is the correct way to use OAuth for mobile and website consuming my own API?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have a question more related to the way OAuth 2 is working but since using IdentityServer to implement OAuth I think it's relevant. I could not find an answer anywhere.

I'm building a website and a mobile app that consumes my own API. Each user of my app will have a username and password, that will give him access to the app/website and though the API to his information.

I'm not sure about the right way to handle the flow for user login:

1. On the website I have my own designed login form. I don't want to move the user to my auth server to login, and then have him approve the information he gives - he is the user on my system - I have access to all information - kida like facebook has a login and access to the informatio - they don't ask what you're willing to give them. So is implicit really the way for this?
2. On the mobile app I also have a login form and now I read here (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-10) that the OAuth approach is to have the login in a WebView?? Doesn't look like facebook login is in a WebView on their mobile app.
3. The approach I was first lookin at is the Resource Owner. Users will login, get the token and the refresh token and can start working against my APIs. But storing my client_id and secret on the mobile app? on the website javascript files? doesn't feel right. I can of course make a call to an API that will mask those and be a proxy to the login process... but... (read #4).
4. In the future I would like to allow access for third-party developers. For them to allow login for users of my system I will use the implicit flow. Also, I plan for those developer accounts to have restricted API access (for example, the number of calls to the API will be limited by plan). What prevents those developers from asking for the username and password of their account on my system on their website, getting the response from my servers with the access token and refresh token, and using my API however they want, without restrictions, and having access to the entire user profile?
5. Lets say I'm sticking to the resource owner flow, receiving back from the server a token and a refresh token. What should I store on the mobile device and how? What should be stored in the browser and how? the refresh token? and each time he opens the app get a new updated token with that refresh token?

**Edit**

Just to clarify, because I find a lot of lectures and articles that explain the process from an API consumer point of view (ie. the third-party developer): I am the API owner and the auth server owner, I'm the owner of the user accounts (they are my users of my services), I'm also my own consumer (though the website and the mobile app), and in the future I want to enable third-party developers to allow my users to login with their accounts of my service (kinda like Facebook or Google)

Comment: Just disable the consent request then or for a specific idp (local accounts)

Comment: @Mardoxx Which can be done by setting `RequireConsent = false` for the client

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that you shouldn't store the `client_secret` in your app, but I doubt you will get around storing the `client_id`. You could disable the consent screen for your app as well, and build a native login view. You need to store the `access_token` and the `refresh_token` on the device (maybe encrypted in a database) if you don't want the user to login everytime they use your app.

As for problem 4, you could do the following:

1. Embed the `client_secret` in your (web) app
2. Set up which hosts have access to your api on the IdentityServer
3. The IdentityServer generates a salt and sends it to the client
4. The client calculates a `session_secret` using `hash(ip_address + session_salt)`
5. The client uses the `session_secret` and the `client_secret` for the API call
6. Server validates the `hash` and `client_secret`

It's nearly impossible to completely prevent someone from using your API. But you should add various rate limiting methods, such as limiting IP addresses, API calls etc. But nothing will stop someone decompiling your app and accessing your `client_id`.